# Badge content overflow in bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using Bootstrap 3 in my project. I am facing issues with badges, The badge contents are overflowing. How do break within the div when it's overflowing? 
[image]

Comment: It'd be much more helpful if you could add a Snippet of your coding.

Comment: Hi, thanks for asking. Here is my snippet  https://codepen.io/jagan/pen/LeapvG